# Is there any error in my Regex usage?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a following string from this [page](http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_cartoon/khan_index.html?mode=list&code=361102&page=1).

```
./khan_index.html?artid=(numbers)&amp;code=361102
```

so i used this regex to get it.

```
\.\/khan_index\.html\?artid=\d+&amp;code=361102
```

The code is as follows;

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_cartoon/khan_index.html?mode=list&code=361102&page=1");
        }

        string pattern = (@"\.\/khan_index\.html\?artid=\d+&amp;code=361102");
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(htmlCode, pattern);
```

I ran the code but the count of `matches` remains 0.

What is the problem?

Comment: Replace `&amp;` with `&`. No need to escape the slash.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  The source has &amp; in it.

Comment: Turns out it is not..... The code works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `&amp;` Can you show content of htmlCode variable or just replace `\.\/khan_index\.html\?artid=\d+&amp;code=361102` within `\.\/khan_index\.html\?artid=\d+&code=361102`

Comment: (blah blah blah)<img src="http://img.khan.co.kr/news/r/170xX/2015/09/09/20150910_JANG.jpg" width="144"></a></span><p><a href="./khan_index.html?artid=201509092207252&amp;code=361102">(blah blah blah)

Comment: Are you sure? Because I just have downloaded the source of page and I see `<a href='./khan_index.html?artid=201509092207252&code=361102'>2015³â 9¿ù 10ÀÏ</a>`

Comment: I must have been mistaken... sorry

Comment: But maybe you have this error because WebClient encodes html code by default and you may to try use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to decode it like `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlCode)`